# Not able to browse loopback api after deploying to now.sh

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, loopback, vercel

I have created a loopback API and deployed it on now.sh.
After deploying I'm able to browse the directory but not able to call API URLs. My project structure is as follow:

[image]

Package.json file:

```
{
"name": "****",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "server/server.js",
"engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
},
"now":{
    "name":"****",
    "alias":["****"],
    "env":{
        "MONGODB_URL":"@lbmongonew",
        "NODE_ENV":"production"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "now:deploy":"now",
    "now:alias":"now alias",
    "now":"npm run now:deploy && npm run now:alias",
    "posttest": "npm run lint && nsp check",
    "start": "node ."
},
"dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "helmet": "^3.10.0",
    "loopback": "^3.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^6.2.0",
    "loopback-connector-mongodb": "^4.0.0",
    "now": "^13.1.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "strong-error-handler": "^3.0.0",
    "todo": "^1.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.17.1",
    "eslint-config-loopback": "^8.0.0"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
},
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"description": "****"}
```

My config.production.json file is as follow:

```
{
"restApiRoot": "/api",
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"port": 3000,
"remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
        "handleErrors": false,
        "normalizeHttpPath": false,
        "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
        "strict": false,
        "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
        "extended": true,
        "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": false
   }}
```

Note: I have not changed host and port because the host is a dynamic host for deployment that keeps on changing on every deployment on now.sh

here it is the directory which I'm able to browse after deployment

[image]

When I browse "https://URL/explorer" than Page not found error is occuring.
What I'm missing here while browsing APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a **now v2**? If so, you need to use a Node Builder in your `now.json` or `package.json` before deploying.

https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/node-js-now-node/